# API calls failing during Spring security default authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I am trying to incorporate password hashing using Bcrypt which required me to add spring security to my project. The issue that I am facing is that whenever I try to call any of my APIs I get the authentication like this:
[image: authentication screen]
and even when I enter correct username and password it fails with the logs:

```
2023-09-20T18:50:37.045+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-09-20T18:50:37.139+05:30  WARN 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2023-09-20T18:50:37.139+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
2023-09-20T18:50:37.144+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:89) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-09-20T18:50:37.158+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-09-20T18:50:37.159+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@30505025
2023-09-20T18:50:37.171+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-09-20T18:50:37.174+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-09-20T18:50:37.243+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/error?continue to session
2023-09-20T18:50:37.244+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-09-20T18:50:37.244+05:30 DEBUG 18632 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@30505025
```

My security config file is as follows:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(String.valueOf(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()));
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and controller is as follows:

```
import com.neighborly.origin.entity.UserRegister;
import com.neighborly.origin.model.UserLogin;
import com.neighborly.origin.model.UserRegistrationRequest;
import com.neighborly.origin.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity registerUser(@RequestBody UserRegistrationRequest request) {
        String username = request.getUsername();
        String password = request.getPassword();
        String email = request.getEmail();
        String id = request.getId();

        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

        // TODO: Save the user to the database or perform other necessary operations
        UserRegister userRegister = new UserRegister();
        userRegister.setId(id);
        userRegister.setUsername(username);
        userRegister.setPassword(password);
        userRegister.setEmail(email);
        try {
            userRepository.save(userRegister);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.toString(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(String.format("%s user registered successfully", username), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have tried with default username and password too but no difference. I am using Java 17 and spring 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test that if all work well with default implementation I recommend you to provide a `UserDetailsService` bean something like this:
It is a default one as example according to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/in-memory.html)

```
  @Bean
  public InMemoryUserDetailsManager users() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
        User.withUsername("myname")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .authorities("read")
            .build()
    );
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
```

Some details about `filterChain` also you should have something like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
    return http.build();
```

}

NOW you can to try to login with `myname` as login and `password` as password. Something like this.

But in controller layer you also have a `registration` here i think you should analyze/read/try with documentation this one implementation. Here I just can add some good references aka **HOW TO**

[JDBC Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/index.html)

[Storage Mechanisms](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/storage.html)

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Although I still have to figure out how to handle csrf issue during testing of POST apis but I tested this with GET api and totally worked. What I fail to understand is why is this required when I am using the default authentication with default username and password?

Comment: Have you tried to disable it yet ? Something like this `http.csrf(c -> c.disable());`

Comment: Yeah I have disabled it with `http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);`.

Comment: Have it solved the problem yet ?

Comment: Yeah, that worked!